# Source for countries/country codes for the entire world?

Tags: google-maps, data, mapinfo

Is there any Google API which would return all the countries in the world with the country code?

Comment: The AJAX API has the list you require? http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html#language-params

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps API family does not have anything like this. There might be other API's that do, but since ISO 3166-1 is fairly static you are probably better off embedding the data rather than retrieving it from an API every time you need it.

You could use [Wikipedia's article on ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes) as a source for the list of countries and codes.

Answer (score 1):

How about [KML Countries at GeoCommons](http://geocommons.com/overlays/101187). It has entries such as:

- Cntryname: Australia, Fipscntry: AS
- Cntryname: Egypt, Fipscntry: EG
- Cntryname: France, Fipscntry: FR
- Cntryname: United States, Fipscntry: US